# How can I separate the output of a wp_query into separate sections

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WP Query that is checking a custom post types metafields.

I have two custom post types:

1. Country
2. Media

The country custom posts type is simply created to pull the content of the media post type into.

The Media CPT contains 2 metafields:

1. The first metafield is a media filter selection that allows the selection of "TV", "Radio", "Digital" and has this ID `_rtl_media_filter`.
2. The second contains a country to associate the post type to and has this ID `_rtl_country_filter`, which is pulling the country CPT name into a dropdown and can be selected from within the media post type.

The aim is to display all the media types that are assiciated with the country CPT when the country CPT is viewed.

I have this loop, which works. But am wondering if I can group a single loops item by media type `_rtl_media_filter`? Rather than creating multiple loops for each?

```
<?php
    // Grab this posts ID
    $post = $wp_query->post;
    $this_id = $post->ID;

    // Query the meta vaules against the posts ID
          $args = array(
            'post_type'     => 'media',
            'meta_query'    =>  array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                        array( // TV
                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                array(
                                        'key' => '_rtl_media_filter',
                                        'value' => 'tv',
                                        'compare' => '=',
                                ),
                                array(
                                        'key' => '_rtl_country_filter',
                                        'value' => $this_id,
                                        'compare' => '=',
                                ),
                        ),
                        array( // DIGITAL
                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                array(
                                        'key' => '_rtl_media_filter',
                                        'value' => 'digital',
                                        'compare' => '=',
                                ),
                                array(
                                        'key' => '_rtl_country_filter',
                                        'value' => $this_id,
                                        'compare' => '=',
                                ),
                        ),
                        array( // RADIO
                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                array(
                                        'key' => '_rtl_media_filter',
                                        'value' => 'radio',
                                        'compare' => '=',
                                ),
                                array(
                                        'key' => '_rtl_country_filter',
                                        'value' => $this_id,
                                        'compare' => '=',
                                ),
                        ),
                ),
           'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );

        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if($the_query -> have_posts()) :
            while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();

            echo '<h2>' . the_title() . '</h2>';

            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        endif;

?>
```

This is how I would like the output:

### |TV|

ITV | ITV2 | ITV3

### |RADIO|

Radio 1 | Radio2

### |DIGITAL|

HUB 1 | HUB 2

Comment: What do you mean multiple loops? This is only one loop with the specific arguments, right?

Comment: Correct, I was wondering if I could group the output by `rtl_media_filter` value

Comment: Do you mean to output also `country` post type which has same `rtl_media_filter` value?

Comment: I've updated my question with the desired output

Comment: Could you insert your output right now? It would be very helpful

Comment: The current output appears as they are entered into wordpress so this could be TV | RADIO | TV | DIGITAL | TV | TV | DIGITAL etc...

Comment: From what i understand you need an order by they key value?

Comment: correct, I would like them grouped

Comment: Insert inside `meta_query` something like this -> `'media_filter' => array(
            'key' => '_rtl_media_filter',
        ),` and then add to the general array `'orderby' => array(
            'media_filter' => 'ASC',
        ),`

Comment: http://prnt.sc/etm535

Comment: Doesn't work but it pointed me in the right direction, ordering by `meta_value` Thanks for your help

Comment: Check [this](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/) and [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218709/order-by-custom-field-value)

Comment: Weird, but for some reason my page is stuck on loading with that added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140188/discussion-between-antonis-tsimourtos-and-aaron).

Answer (score 0):

So After Antonis pointed out about ordering by meta_value I figured out the way it can be done. For anyone else trying this the solution lies with these couple of lines:

```
       'orderby' => 'meta_value',
       'meta_key' => '_rtl_media_filter',
```

Add those to the bottom of your loop query.